# Using regex in Java Programming

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to extract parts of string object (i.e. substrings). I am having a big string consisting of alphanumeric characters. I want to count the number of substrings present in the said string matching certain criteria.

An example of my matching criteria is that the substring should contain atleast one uppercase letter and there should be no digits in it.

Comment: Sorry but it is unclear what you are asking.  Please visit the [help], take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Write some code..that always helps. Or, research online about string manipulation. Good Luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static int countMatchInString(){
    int result = 0;
    String complexString = "Addf34Dffgh32FxFD345xxxx43";
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\P{N}*\\p{Lu}\\P{N}*").matcher(complexString);

    while (matcher.find()){
        result++;
    }
    return result;

}
```

This should help. Output: 3

Comment: Incorrect regex. Substring `FxFD` should match, but only `Fx` does. This regex would fix it `"\\P{N}*\\p{Lu}\\P{N}*"`, with full Unicode support. See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pL3rR1/1).

Comment: Thanks for sharing such useful site.